# Как передать Cookie в HttpWebRequest для Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, .net

В полном .NET куки передаются с помощью CookieContainer:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

А в Compact Framework, класс HttpWebRequest не содержит свойства CookieContainer. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на вопрос: надо напрямую работать с http-заголовками.

```
string cookie;

if (response.Headers["Set-Cookie"] != null)
    cookie = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];

if (cookie != null)
    request.Headers["Cookie"]= cookie;
```